# How to resize large size image?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have forgot what is added in manifest file but in xml file i use android:scaleY="1" and android:scaleX=".9"
 Can anyone help me to find ou this solution.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Bitmap` for your `ImageView` like this

`Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);`

Specify width and height that you want to set for your `ImageView`.